# Any ideas on Iterating over dataframe and applying regex?

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteritems

This may be a rudimentary problem but I am new to pandas.

I have a csv dataframe and I want to **iterate over each row** to **extract all the string information in a specific column through regex.** . (The reason why I am using regex is because eventually I want to make a separate dataframe of that column)

I tried iterating through for loop but I got ton of errors. So far, It looks like for loop reads each input row as a list or series rather than a string (correct me if i'm wrong). My main functions are **iteritems()** and **findall()** but no good results so far. How can I approach this problem?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df =pd.read_csv('foobar.csv')
df[['column1','column2, 'TEXT']]
```

My approach looks like this:

```
for Individual_row in df['TEXT'].iteritems():
   parsed = re.findall('(.*?)\:\s*?\[(.*?)\], Individual_row)
   res = {g[0].strip() : g[1].strip() for g in parsed}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following instead of loop:

```py
df['new_TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].apply(lambda x: [g[0].strip(), g[1].strip()] for g in re.findall('(.*?)\:\s*?\[(.*?)\]', x), na_action='ignore' )
```

This will create a new column with your resultant data.

Comment: I ran through your code and got an error saying 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap' But thank you for the insight!! I'll look into applymap()

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you try the updated solution?

Comment: I tired the updated answer and got "expected string or bytes-like object." 
By the way, the dtype of df['TEXT'] appear as 'object'. I tired to change dtype into string using .astype(str) but it doesn't do anything.